# a class extends from generic super class but not specify the generic type

Tags: java, generics

I write a generic abstract class TestSuper, the remarkable is that it has a method "execute" with a param Callable, the generic type of Callable is T, and T is irrelevant to V.
this is the code:

```
//my abstract class 
public abstract class TestSuper<V>
{
    public abstract void callExecute(V value);

    public <T> T execute(Callable<T> callable)
    {
        T call = null;
        try
        {
            call = callable.call();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return call;
    }
}
```

Then I write sub class like this:

```
//the sub class that not specify the generic type from TestSuper
public class TestSub extends TestSuper
{
    @Override
    public void callExecute(Object value)
    {
        Boolean result = execute(new Callable<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception
            {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am confused about the type of variable "result", because this code come with compile time error.
like this:

```
java: incompatible types
  required: java.lang.Boolean
  found:    java.lang.Object
```

If I replace "Boolean result" to "Object result", the error disappear.

If I specify the generic type when difine the TestSub, there is no error too.

```
public class TestSub extends TestSuper<Object>
{
    @Override
    public void callExecute(Object value)
    {
        Boolean result = execute(new Callable<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception
            {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

how to interpret the generic type in this case?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Issue:**

Since you are extending the raw type `TestSuper`, the `execute` method you get will be the one which you get after type-erasure. So, the method signature really becomes like this:

```
public Object execute(Callable callable)
```

During the type-erasure, the type parameters are replaced with their near-most bound. Since, the type parameter was `<T>` without any bound, near-most bound is taken as `Object`. That is why, you are getting that compilation error, as compiler sees `execute` method with return type `Object`, and you are storing the result in `Boolean` type. In fact, you should have got a compiler error at `@Override` annotation only, because your `callExecute` method is not overriding the method in super class. The return type should be `Object` instead of `void`.

Of course, when you change `Boolean result` to `Object result`, it would work.

See [JLS §4.8 - Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from
>   its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds
>   to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to
>   C.

---

So, in 2nd case, since you are extending a parameterized type `TestSuper<Object>`, the `execute` method will now be generic method only. And hence, the type `T` is inferred as `Boolean`.

Comment: +1 Great explanation Rohit. Especially the JLS reference it cleared a thing for me too :)